# DataTable.js implement a filter to hide rows by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I created this filter to compare the index of the row to starttime and endtime variables. The idea is that the values of starttime and endtime correspond to the rows in the table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var startTime = 0;
            var endTime = 23;    
            $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
               function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
                   alert("in");
                   if (iDataIndex < startTime + 1)
                       return false;
                   if (iDataIndex > endTime + 1)
                       return false;
                   return true;
               }

           );


           var table = $('#example').DataTable({
               "bAutoWidth":false,
               "scrollX": true,
               "scrollCollapse": true,
               "scrollY": $(slotValueGrid).height()*0.75,
               "searching": false,
               "bLengthChange": false,
               "bPaginate": false,
               "bInfo": false

           });
           new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table, {
               leftColumns: 1
           });




       });
       function displayAdvertRight() {

           var e = document.getElementById("startTimeDDL");
           startTime =parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value,10);
           e = document.getElementById("endTimeDDL")
           endTime = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value,10);
           $("#example").dataTable().api().fnDraw();

       }
```

I have tried all the following calls to get the function to filter but it won't work, I always get a response that $(...).dataTable(...).api(...).fnDraw is not a function or something along those lines and I have looked at the section in the faq regarding the dataTable vs DataTable but it does not solve anything

```
$("#example").dataTable().api().fnDraw();

$("#example").dataTable().api().draw();

$("#example").DataTable().fnDraw();

$("#example").DataTable().draw();
```

I cant figure out how to get the filter event to fire since I can't seem to call draw()

Comment: is it `});` exrta before `function displayAdvertRight() {`??

Comment: Sorry forgot to put in the document.ready(), I have edited my code above. I can't place the displayAdvertRight() inside the document.ready() as then I receive this error displayAdvertRight is not defined on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table.draw()` does not work because it is defined inside the `$(document).ready` scope. You must have global `table` variable, then it will be accessible in your `displayAdvertRight()` function too. I.e

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
   table = $('#example').DataTable({    
   ...
});
```

I get the impression that you have two `<select>`-boxes, `startTime` and `endTime`, and the custom filter should filter out rowindexes (`iDataIndex`) outside those `<select>`'s range?

```
<select id="startTime"></select>
<select id="endTime"></select>
```

The custom filter can be simplified a little bit :

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        var startTime = parseInt($("#startTime").val()),
            endTime = parseInt($("#endTime").val());
        return ((iDataIndex >= startTime) && (iDataIndex <= endTime));
    }
);
```

Then all you have to do is calling `table.draw()` on `<select>` change event :

```
$("#startTime, #endTime").on('change', function() {
    table.draw();
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/f09g7ssa/**

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that this solution does work, but why must table be in the global scope if I am not referencing it by variable name but instead by  $("#example").dataTable().api()

Comment: @ObiEff I cannot say why it did not worked with `$("#example").DataTable().draw();` etc without seeing the specific code. It should defently work - see example with `table` in the "ready scope" using `draw()` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/f09g7ssa/1/** ...Perhaps you called `displayAdvertRight()` somewhere immediately before the page had finished loading?

Comment: The call happens from a button which is only clickable when the page is ready.

Comment: What if I have more than 1 table?

Comment: @PedroJoaquín see this -> **https://stackoverflow.com/q/55242822/1407478**